# Is it possible to hack the data of Android app even if it's offline?

Tags: android, security

I'm building a simple Android application for my self. It is a simple password manager where I can store all my accounts. I just want to know if is it possible to hack or extract the data of Android app even if it's offline? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are the password hashes stored server or client-side? If the passwords are stored client-side, then yes, it is indeed possible. If the passwords are stored in plaintext, all the better for the attacker who has local access to the device.

My hope would be that you used symmetric-key encryption on the passwords which can only be decrypted with your master password utilized as the key and that you minimize plaintext exposure even within memory.

Comment: Yes it's installed on the client side.

Comment: I just want to view my passwords within the app :)

Comment: Then it is indeed vulnerable to offline attacks.

Comment: If you just want to view the passwords within the app, encrypt them using a symmetric-key algorithm, and use a master-password as the key to decrypt them and then display them. It's the smallest measure of security you can provide in this case. There are always logic errors that they can exploit, but that is a good start.

Comment: Thank you @DeepS1X

Comment: No problem. Shoot me any more questions you might have later and I will be happy to discuss it further with you.

Comment: Yes. That would only be possible via exploit or directly from google/(your hardware manufacturer)/CSP, and as most people do not want to burn exploits for mobile platforms right now, I doubt that you will come across such a problem.

Comment: @DeepS1X: You wrote "use a master-password as the key" -  this insecure and dangerous! Never misuse a key as password. Always use a key derivation algorithm like PBKDF2 for generating a key based on a password.

Answer (score 1):

No one can transfer data to a remote server when the device is offline, but there are other possible ways considering your problem like,

1. Create a program to collect data from your database and send it through SMS (Considering passwords are textual data and small in size)
2. Create a program to collect data and stay in low profile and send them to a server when the device became online

Technically possible, But don't worry, chances for someone doing something like this is very low,
Go with your idea and encrypt data if you can to avoid easy stealing.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I was assuming local machine access, but I guess backdoor implementations would be just as good at retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would always assume yes with these kind of things. I would recommend looking into encryption of the data, a simple splash screen for an app password would work. I would make sure that the private encryption key something that can only be generated by that password entered at the lock/splash screen. Other than that, on stock roms you should be alright but obviously dont leave fishy apps on  your device. If I was building this I might even look into 2 factor auth via nfc as well.

Comment: What would you suggest as an NFC implementation? A hardware token of some sort containing another encryption key for a secondary layer of encryption? I do not think this is necessary for his implementation, as carrying around a hardware token for your Android device seems like overkill for a simple password manager. Assuming, of course, that these passwords are not nuclear codes. In that case, the availability detriment would be offset by the confidentiality gain.

Comment: Its definitly not "needed" but I would go for 2 factor via my yubikey and I would throw a self destruct feature in as well, lol.

Comment: While we are at it, I will purchase the fallout shelter and the biometric scanner just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It may be possible!
Internet is not only thing which connect port or sharing of port,
There are many options like bluetooth or Hostpot...
Through which we can connect two device jz we have to write program which access these tools and gives command to victims phone....

For online
We have msfvenom payload to hack any android...
Its quite easy process in this process we forword victims phone port to attacker os....
Its so easy

For offline services we can hack device using BT remote control or same as with wifi...